# Time-Scheduled Screensaver

Tags: screensaver, paid-applications, slideshow

I'm looking for a way to run a time-scheduled screensaver slideshow. For example:

- From 13:00 to 16:00, run a screensaver that cycles through three images every 10 minutes
- From 16:01 to 18:30, run a screensaver that cycles through **three different images** for every 10 minutes

... and so on. Does anyone know how to do this?